# How to use parApply .scheduling argument

Tags: r, parallel-processing

How does one use the `.scheduling` argument to the `parApply` functions in the R `parallel` package?

The documentation defines the parameter as:

> **.scheduling**
>   should tasks be statically allocated to nodes or dynamic
>   load-balancing used?

What are possible values of the `.scheduling` argument, and what effect do they have?

Comment: Given the description, it should be a boolean.

Comment: @F.Privé With `FALSE` meaning "statically allocated" and `TRUE` meaning "dynamic load-balancing" ? If that's the case, I'd accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Maybe you should try the two with an easy example like computing sqrt(i) over a long range. Dynamic scheduling should be slower for this.